# Contact form issue when trying to receive emails

Tags: javascript, html, api, contact-form

When I fill out the text fields and input an email into the text box with the placeholder that says "email", nothing sends to my email after I click submit. The only time something does send to my email after I click submit is when I type in my personal email into the "email" textbox. My personal email is what recieves anything submitted from this form. What am I doing wrong?...

I utilized "smtpJS.com" to encrypt and establish securetoken key for smtp through "elasticemail.com" to enable my domain for form submissions to my personal email when someone fills out the form.

JavaScript

```
/*contact form/Send email*/
        /*SmtpJS.com security encryption for host, username, and passowrd*/
 function sendEmail(){
                Email.send({

                SecureToken : "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
                To : 'kalvitzjames1@gmail.com',
                From : document.getElementById("email").value,
                Subject : "New Contact Form Enquiry",
                Body : "<br> Name: " + document.getElementById("name").value
                + "<br> Email: " + document.getElementById("email").value
                + "<br> Phone: " + document.getElementById("phone").value
                + "<br> Message: " + document.getElementById("message").value

                })
                
                .then(message => alert("Thank you for your Message!"));
            }
```

HTML

```
<!--SmtpJS.com (for form emails)-->
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>


            <!--calling email function-->
           <form onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false;">

            
            <h3>Get in touch</h3>
            

            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>

            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>

            <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="phone" required>

            <textarea id="message" rows="4" placeholder="How can I help?"></textarea>

            <button type="submit">Send</button>

           </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Link to code on my github

(https://github.com/jameskalvitz/Personal-Website)

Comment: @isherwood I tried my best for my first post ever. I'm learning brother. Takes time. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: "Issue" is still very vague. Did you read [ask]? This is basic communication clarity, not anything specific to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the email look like it would originate from the filler of this form?

Usually email providers forbid to use "arbitrary" email addresses in the `from` field. Otherwise you basically would build a spam bot, with which you send emails on behalf of someone else (using their real email addresses but without authentication).

If this is a sort of contact form you rather should send from your email address to your email address and populate the `reply-to` field in the email header for your convenience.

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around it. If I fill out the form and enter the same email used to create the account on elasticmail.com, that's when I'll see anything in my Gmail. Anyone else typing their email into the form will not send me anything. 
My email will work and show up like this:
"name: John doe email: kalvitzjames1@gmail.com phone no: 1234567891 message: test one"               If someone doesn't use the email shown above when filling out the form I don't recieve anything. the email used above is the email I used to create and manually set up this form to send emails to.

Comment: ...and that is exactly the way it should be. Like I answered before, you cannot set an arbitrary email address as the sender, since you would then be able to send emails on their behalf and make them look like they truly originate from them. This might be what you want here, but just think of anyone sending a contract or important information that way. How would you be sure, that the origin is not coming from "bad people". To avoid this, email providers block such behaviour and usually you are in need for authentication to make sure the sender is the real sender.

Comment: The common way is to send contact form emails from dedicated email addresses that you own to the same one or another one that you own. That way you stay in your authenticated regime. All other information like the email address etc. of the form will be content of the email body. Furthermore, if you want to have the option to directly reply on such incoming emails, you may set the `reply-to` field in the email header to the filler's email address (instead of `from`).

Comment: Ok i am starting to grasp what youre saying. I am sorry, I am just new and learning all this. When you say "you may set the reply-to field in the email header to the filler's email address (instead of from)." would you be able to create a quick example using my code in the way youd do it?

Comment: That's what we are here for :-) It is as easy as adding `ReplyAddress: document.getElementById("email").value` to the `Email.send()` function, see https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2018/12/07/smtpjs-now-supports-multiple-attachments-replyto-and-sender-name/ PS: You may want to sanitize the form before eventually digesting it, i.e. remove bad entities in the values of the form fields that makes you vulnerable to XSS attacks etc.

Comment: Ok so I am getting close but i am still having the same issue. When you say sanitize, how would i go about that as well to avoid XSS attacks and etc.?

Comment: I tried the ReplyAddress: but it still is not working :/

Comment: Have you set `From: 'kalvitzjames1@gmail.com'` as well?

Comment: yes I have set From: 'kalvitzjames1@gmail.com'